# List<> getResultados retorna lista com elementos iguais

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

Olá.

Tenho a seguinte tabela no mysql:

```
create table resultado(
data varchar(10),
premio varchar(3),
loteria varchar(5),
milhar varchar(10),
primary key(data, premio, loteria)
);
```

A classe que representa essa tabela em Java:

```
public class Resultado {
    private static String data;
    private static String premio;
    private static String loteria;
    private static String milhar;
}
```

E o código que extraio os resultados para uma lista:

```
public static List<Resultado> getResultados() throws SQLException {
    List<Resultado> resultados = new ArrayList<Resultado>();
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    String sql = "select * from resultado";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.execute();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Resultado result = new Resultado();
        Resultado.setData(resultSet.getString("data"));
        Resultado.setPremio(resultSet.getString("premio"));
        Resultado.setLoteria(resultSet.getString("loteria"));
        Resultado.setMilhar(resultSet.getString("milhar"));
        resultados.add(result);
    }
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
    return resultados;
}
```

Porém quando imprimo no console, todos os resultados são iguais ao último resultado inserido.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está usando `static` em todas as variáveis:

```
    private static String data;
    private static String premio;
    private static String loteria;
    private static String milhar;
```

ous seja, essas variáveis (campos) irão ser únicas para a classe, nem necessita de instância para acessar (em outras palavras, o mesmo valor independente da instância).

Remova o `static` tornando essas variáveis em variáveis de instância

```
public class Resultado {
    private String data;
    private String premio;
    private String loteria;
    private String milhar;
}
```

altere os métodos para setar de acordo, exemplo:

```
public void setData(...
```

e as respectivas chamadas para acessar esses métodos:

```
result.setData(resultSet.getString("data"));
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui.

Muito obrigado!